# API Requests throwing a 404 error due to bad URL, URL is being changed automatically, what is going on?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm having an API pull an ID then use that ID to finish a URL for an API request.

```
def get_id(hostname,  headers, verbose):
    id_query = {'name': hostname}
    id_response = requests.get(url = "/api/", headers = headers, verify = False, timeout=120, params=id_query)
    id_status = id_response.status_code
    id_payload = id_response.json()
    id = id_payload["results"][0]["id"]
    print(id)
    return id

url = f"url.com/api/client/{id}"
```

When the URL is tried in my API request I get an HTTP 404 error, when I print url I get a (id,) added to the end of the URL instead of just the ID. Example if I had the ID as 1

`url.com/api/client/(1,)`

When I print just the variable, `print(id)` I get just the number value, no added (number,). What is going on here? I also tried using `.format()` with no change.

Comment: You are shadowing the built-in [`id`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) function by the way.

Comment: Should've pointed out, `id` is just my example, real var is a different name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `url` parameter in the `requests.get` call is probably incorrect - an API endpoint rarely ends in a forward slash.

Comment: What does `id_payload` look like?

Comment: And how are you calling your `get_id` method?